# PyPlot add timestamps to the x-axis of a subplot with millisecond precision, at an angle

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to use PyPlot to plot some time-stamped values with the timestamp on the x-axis. Here is a toy version of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ts = [' 13:25:36.347', ' 13:25:36.350', ' 13:25:36.353', ' 13:25:36.357', ' 13:25:36.366']
ts = pd.to_datetime(ts,format=" %H:%M:%S.%f")

y = pd.DataFrame([-0.005563,-0.000910,0.002366,0.002868,-0.000303],dtype=float)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(ts,y)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S.%f'))
ax.legend(loc="best")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This has a plot with one subplot because I think the use of a subplot might affect the answer.

In reality I have a lot more observations than this, and I want to have as many ticks as possible without having the labels overlap, so the ticks need to be at an angle or even vertical. But if I say `ax.xticks(rotation=90)`I'm told that the axes object has no such attribute.

The second issue is the precision of the fractional second. I would like this to be centiseconds or milliseconds, but am not sure how to specify that. The things I've found don't seem to work with mdates.DateFormatter.

UPDATES

Redox pointed out that rotation issues are addressed with `ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=90)`. Also said that script is throwing an error but I tested before posting and it runs fine for me.

I found out I can one tick every .1 sec with `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MicrosecondLocator(interval=100000))` which is fine for my purposes. But I still can't figure out how to chop the five useless zeros off of the tick labels.

Comment: The above code errors out at ax.plot() with msg `KeyError: (slice(None, None, None), None)`

Comment: But, changing `ts` as a column of `y` before plotting along with using `ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=90)`, I was able to do what you needed to do, Will that work?

Comment: Strange...it runs fine for me. But yes, that takes care of the rotation, thanks. Now if I can only figure out how to cut 3-4 zeros off of the timestamp. Also how to get more ticks. When I run it with 1000 observations, I only get 8 ticks

Comment: Bit more complicated to put into a comment... pls see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I hope this will take care of your needs.

1. To handle the number of zeros to be shown in the ticklabel, you can use `FuncFormatter()`, and define the function to be run. Basically, the same ticklabel will be shown, but removing the last 3 (or change if you want more or less) digits.
2. To fix the number of labels to be shown, you can use `MaxNLocator(N)` inside `set_major_locator()` which will show `N-1` labels. I have used a function which will get the number of labels based on the length of `ts`. Make sure you change it to fix your needs ... or just give a single number like 10
3. As mentioned, `set_tick_params(rotation=90)` will handle the labels.

Updated code is as below..

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ts = [' 13:25:36.347', ' 13:25:36.350', ' 13:25:36.353', ' 13:25:36.357', ' 13:25:36.366']
ts = pd.to_datetime(ts,format=" %H:%M:%S.%f")
y = pd.DataFrame([-0.005563,-0.000910,0.002366,0.002868,-0.000303],dtype=float)
y['date']=ts
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(y['date'], y[0])

## Number of ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(len(ts)/2+1))

## Custom formatting
myFormat = lambda x, pos: mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S.%f')(x)[:-3]
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(myFormat))

##Rotation
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=90)

ax.legend(loc="best")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]